# Get hyperlinks of an smartArt object VBA

Tags: vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

I want to get the hyperlinks that an smartArt object has in powerpoint. Normally the Slide hyperlinks are stored on `slide.Hyperlinks` but the ones that are inside smartArt are not appearing.

Anyone knows how can I access to them and see to what slide are they pointing?

Comment: Have you tried adding a watch to the SmartArt object and reading through the properties to see if it has a collection of Hyperlinks itself?

Comment: Yes but no luck... I also saw here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522561/macro-vba-powerpoint-smartart-hyperlinks how to add hyperlinks but in the watch you cannot see ActionSettings

Comment: Are you using PPT 2010? This was addressed in PPT 2013. In PPT 2010 and earlier, you will need to enumerate the smartart shape and go over the TextFrame.TextRange.ActionSettings to read this information.

Comment: Yes I am using PPT 2013 and I cannot watch ActionSettings. I tried to do it but ir is not available. It says `<Object doesn't support this property or method>`

Comment: Old topic, but the SmartArt objects still seem to be not supporting HL retrieval. Running Office 365 (PowerPoint 2016). The .count-property works, then a FOR ... EACH loop will cause an automation error. Any idea?